# SASS: Añadir valores a una variable

Tags: css, sass

¿En SASS se puede añadir valores a una variable?
Algo así como:

```
$variable: "texto"
@for $i from 1 through 13
  $variable .: $variable + $i
```

---

NO, no estáis entendiendo lo que pregunto el punto se usa en PHP, en Javascript, ponen un + yo tengo una variable con valor de un id de un selector, de esta manera `$variable = ".caja-1"` pero tengo 20 cajas, `.caja-1, .caja-2, .caja-3, .caja-4, etc  para no picar el texto 20 veces, hago un for: @for $i from 1 through 20` y `$variable-#{$i}` eso devuelve `.caja-1, .caja-2, .caja-3, .caja-4,` pero ahora quiero guardar esos resultados en una única variable `$resultado: .caja-1, .caja-2, .caja-3, .caja-4` a ver si se entiende así.

Comment: si se puede $color: #333333;, creo que se debe crearlos arriba

Answer (score 0):

intenta quitar el "."

algo así:

```
$variable: "texto"

@for $i from 1 through 13
 .#{$variable}-#{$i}
```

Nos cuentas!